# How can I install python-setuptools-git on precise?

Tags: 12.04, installation, python

I see there is a package for this beginning with Quantal, but where can I get it for Precise?

Answer (score 1):

You can install this by running the following command:

```
sudo easy_install setuptools_git
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `pip` to install Python packages from the Python Package Index (PyPi) where [setuptools-git](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools-git) is hosted.

```
sudo pip install setuptools-git
```

You may need to install [python-pip [image: Install python-pip]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-pip) first, if you don't have it yet.

This is favourable over `easy_install`. See [Why use pip over easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220404/1254292) for why.

---

As you can see on [searching the Ubuntu packages page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=setuptools+git&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), it's only included in Ubuntu since Quantal as you've noticed already. The Python package manager Pip is the best alternative here, in my opinion.